# Django admin add view popup dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-admin

How can I pass in an extra `GET` parameter in the add view popup box in the Django admin?

Basically I have a `+` sign in a foreign key, and when I click on it, it opens a popup box to add a new object of that type.

The problem is that I am using some custom Ajax code in the popup box, and I need to find a way to update only the field that is opened the dialog box (assuming there might be other foreign key fields).

The only solution I can think of is to somehow pass in a `GET` parameter so that I know which field should be updated.

Any ideas?  I just need a push in the right direction in order to complete this

Right now I am doing something like this to update the field. and I want to make this dynamic

```
if ($('#id_avatar').length) {
  $('#id_avatar', opener.document).append($('<option selected="selected"></option>').attr('value', data.obj_id).text(data.obj__unicode__));
     }
```

I guess I somehow reloading the select box in the original page could be an option since at this point its already saved in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the fieldsets in `change_form.html`. not sure if its the best approach but it seems to be working for me. 
Now i can pass a `source_field` to know what field called the popup so i can later updated the proper field with Jquery

```
{% for fieldset in adminform %}
{#  {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}#}
    <fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
        {% if fieldset.name %}<h2>{{ fieldset.name }}</h2>{% endif %}
        {% if fieldset.description %}
            <div class="description">{{ fieldset.description|safe }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        {% for line in fieldset %}
            <div class="form-row{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if not line.has_visible_field %} hidden{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
                {% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{{ line.errors }}{% endif %}
                {% for field in line %}
                    <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
                        {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                        {% if field.is_checkbox %}
                            {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
                        {% else %}
                            {{ field.label_tag }}
                            {% if field.is_readonly %}
                                <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
                            {% else %}
                                {% if field.field.name == 'avatar' %}
                                    <select id="id_avatar" name="avatar">
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                                    </select><a href="/admin/core/multimedia/add/?_to_field=id&source_field=avatar" class="add-another" id="add_id_avatar" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"> <img src="/static/admin/img/icon_addlink.gif" width="10" height="10" alt="Add Another"></a>
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ field.field }}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if field.field.help_text %}
                            <p class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```